# Retrofit: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for CustomClass

Tags: java, android, networking, retrofit

I've created a custom implementation of `Call<T>`, here is the custom class without the custom code, just the forward code for you to see.

```
public class CachedCall<T> implements Call<T> {

private final Call<T> delegate;

public CachedCall(Call<T> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public Response<T> execute() throws IOException {
    return delegate.execute();
}

@Override
public void enqueue(Callback<T> callback) {
    delegate.enqueue(callback);
}

public void enqueueWithCache(final CachedCallback<T> callback) {
    delegate.enqueue(callback);
}

@Override
public boolean isExecuted() {
    return delegate.isExecuted();
}

@Override
public void cancel() {
    delegate.cancel();
}

@Override
public boolean isCanceled() {
    return delegate.isCanceled();
}

@Override
public Call<T> clone() {
   return new CachedCall<>(delegate.clone());
}

@Override
public Request request() {
    return delegate.request();
}
```

}

And then in my ApiService, I used this custom implementation on some of my call, and the default one on some other, exemple:

```
public interface APIService {

@GET("categories")
Call<List<Categorie>> categories(@Query("tag") String tag);

@GET("categories/{categorie}/quotes")
CachedCall<List<Gif>> gifs(@Path("categorie") String categorie);
```

When methods with the custom one are called, I got a crash:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for CustomClass.
                                                                 Tried:
                                                                  * retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
                                                                  * retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory
                                                                   at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
                                                                   at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:201)
                                                                   at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:232)
                                                                    ... 21 more
```

Do I need to register my custom implementation with Retrofit somewhere?

Comment: Are you using RxJava2?

Comment: Nop, I don't. I saw some answers that state to add ".addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())" to solve the issue, but it didn't work.

Comment: can you post your retrofit service call?.

Comment: You only require RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create() when you want to work with observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my own issue.

You need to create and register your own CallAdapter.Factory:

```
public class CachedCallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {

final Executor callbackExecutor;

public CachedCallAdapterFactory(Executor callbackExecutor) {
    this.callbackExecutor = callbackExecutor;
}

@Override
public CallAdapter<Call<?>> get(final Type returnType, final Annotation[] annotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (getRawType(returnType) != CachedCall.class) {
        return null;
    }
    final Type responseType = getParameterUpperBound(0, (ParameterizedType) returnType);
    return new CallAdapter<Call<?>>() {
        @Override public Type responseType() {
            return responseType;
        }

        @Override public <R> Call<R> adapt(Call<R> call) {
            return new CachedCall<>(callbackExecutor, call, responseType, retrofit, annotations);
        }
    };
}
```

}

And then register it when you create your Retrofit instance:

```
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(new CachedCallAdapterFactory(new DefaultExecutor()))
            .build();
```

Your `DefaultExecutor` just need to run its `Runnable`

```
    private class DefaultExecutor implements Executor {

    @Override
    public void execute(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: And there is also a sample which is similar on the retrofit github repository https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/ErrorHandlingAdapter.java.